# Find factors of the square of a number n that do not divide n and are less than n

Tags: prime-factorization

> Let $n=2^{23}3^{17}$. How many factors of $n^2$ are less than $n$ but do not divide $n$?

I am unable to solve the problem above.

My question is, how does one determine what factors are less than $n$, considering directly comparing the numbers is not an option when we're working with very large ones in the problem?

Is there a method to compare the size of numbers based on their prime factorization?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, for each fixed  $b$ you can solve $2^a\times 3^b=n$, analytically, and then you'd know all the exponents $a$ that worked for that $b$.  Tedious, certainly, but not difficult.  For instance, with $b=10$ we get $a$ slightly greater than $34$, so the "good" exponents $a$ are $24, \cdots, 34$.

Comment: Since here we're only looking at numbers of the form $2^a3^b$ it's not too difficult. $2^a3^b < 2^{23}3^{17} \iff 2^{a-23} < 3^{17-b}$, and unless $\frac{a-23}{17-b}$ is close to $\frac{\log 3}{\log 2}$ a fairly coarse estimate tends to work.

Answer (score 1):

$n^2$ has $(46+1)(34+1)$ factors.
Of those, $\frac{(46+1)(34+1)+1}{2}$ of them are at most $n$.
Of those, $(23+1)(17+1)$ of them divide $n$.

Hence, there are ... (fill in the blank) factors of $n^2$ that are smaller than $n$ and do not divide $n$.

Comment: Clever method.  $\quad$

Comment: It's a well-known problem in math competitions. One of those where the right interpretation makes it much easier.

Comment: Never saw it before...glad to add it to list.  Thanks!